# Hbase starts on slave but fails on reamining slaves in linux

Tags: hadoop, hbase

I am using hadoop 1.2.1 and hbase 0.94.20.I created a cluster of 5 slave when i started hbase by using ./start-hbase.sh it start the services on one slave but other slaves unable to start...

my Hbase-site.xml file is

```
 <configuration>
<property>
        <name>hbase.rootdir</name>
        <value>hdfs://master:54310/opt/hbase-0.94.20</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>hbase.cluster.distributed</name>
        <value>true</value>
    </property>
 <property>
        <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort</name>
        <value>2222</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>hbase.zookeeper.quorum</name>
        <value>master</value>
    <description>
                </description>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.dataDir</name>
        <value>/opt/hbase-0.94.20/tmp</value>
    </property>
</configuration>

and /etc/hosts file is
127.0.0.1   localhost ubuntu    
10.10.73.42 master sitmaster-HP-Compaq-6200-Pro-SFF-PC 
10.10.73.5  slave1 sit2-HP-Pro-2110 
10.10.73.25 slave2  sit-HP-Pro-2110
# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

Comment: Provide the error you are getting ?

Comment: HRegionServer not running on slaves... only one slave able to start HRegionServer

Comment: when i restart the pc then it starts the HRegionServer on slaves but after restarting the services it fails to start

Comment: That is OK, but there should be some error behind this failure, check for the log files in your log directory.

Comment: slave1: regionserver running as process 9580. Stop it first.
slave: starting regionserver, logging to /opt/hbase-0.94.20/bin/../logs/hbase-root-regionserver-sit7-HP-Pro-2110.out